# Can you measure ECG from a single location?

Tags: human-biology, cardiology

I want to make a DIY bracelet to measure my ECG. All I need is the interbeat interval.

Can I design a bracelet on one arm only, with two electrodes slightly spaced from one another, and figure out the beat from the conduction timing differences down the arm?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot build the classic ECG using only 1 hand.

Probably, you can measure HR - heart rate accordingly to pressure detection and similar sensors and from that you can *simulate* ECG by picture. Simulate I mean you cannot build any reliably ECG curve on the monitor, but can show some waves after every heart beat.

Comment: I definitely want to stick with electrical activity for now-- it's proved more reliable than pressure or photoplesmograph sensors at the wrist. I'm curious whether you think it's possible to *only* extract the heart beat from 2 electrodes on a single wrist. We don't need the classic ECG waveform, only the heartbeat  .

Answer (score 0):

With a **single electrode**, it is impossible to get an EKG as it has to have biopotential from **two points** (it is impossible to gett voltage from a battery using only one terminal).

Regarding **EKG from single arm**, yes it is possible to get clean EKG from shoulder.